# How to create custom graphs for dask dataframes?

Tags: python, dataframe, optimization, dask

I'm trying to paralelize some operations to be done on a Dask Dataframe but I'm not completely understanding the best way to do it.

For example, I'm reading a dask dataframe from parquet and I want to add one unit to the first column by one and two to the second column:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
ddf = dd.read_parquet('dataframe')
ddf['a'] = ddf['a'] + 1
ddf['b'] = ddf['b'] + 2
ddf.visualize()
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8h50.png) is the graph of this computation. (The dataframe was created with 2 partitions).

As can be seen, the two operations are done one after another, where we know that they could be done in parallel (at least parts of it) because they are adding some value to different columns.

Thus, I tried to paralelize these operations by using delayed functions instead:

```py
from dask import delayed
import dask.dataframe as dd

@delayed
def increment(df, x, val):
    print('Type: ',type(df))
    df[x] = df[x] + val
    return df

@delayed
def overwrite(df1 , df2, col):
    df1[col] = df2[col]
    return df1

ddf = dd.read_parquet('dataframe')
op1 = increment(ddf[['a']], 'a', 1)
op2 = increment(ddf[['b']], 'b', 2) 
op3 = overwrite(ddf, op1, 'a')
op4 = overwrite(op3, op2, 'b')
op4.visualize()
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDTHX.png) is the graph of this computation and, as can be seen, some part of the work is being done in parallel. Of course, these operations are very simple and this is an overkill but it's just to demonstrate the point.

However, I am printing the type of the input dataframe inside the `increment` function and, for my surprise, when I run the `op4.compute()`, the type is `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` while I was expecting it to be `dask.dataframe.core.DataFrame`.

Then I decided to `delay` the parquet file reading:

```py
@delayed
def read(name):
    return dd.read_parquet(name)

ddf = read('dataframe')
op1 = increment(ddf[['a']], 'a', 1)
op2 = increment(ddf[['b']], 'b', 2) 
op3 = overwrite(ddf, op1, 'a')
op4 = overwrite(op3, op2, 'b')
op4.visualize()
```

The [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCuWv.png) shows that the jobs are being done in parallel and when I run `op4.compute()` the type of the input dataframe in `increment` function is `dask.dataframe.core.DataFrame` what is I was expecting.

However, the type of `op4` is a `dask.delayed.Delayed`, which means that when I compute it I get an `dask.dataframe.core.DataFrame` and so, in order to get the final dataframe, it's necessary to apply compute two times:

```py
op4.compute().compute()

      a  b
index      
0      2  3
1      2  3
2      2  3
3      2  3
4      2  3
5      2  3
6      2  3
7      2  3
8      2  3
9      2  3
```

We also created the graph in a manual way (using a dictionary) like shown in the documentation. We would like , however, to understand if the delayed version shown above is the best approach to deal with this situation. Online documentation seems to only show the delayed approach used together with lists of values and not dataframes.

Concluding, what is the best way to paralelize jobs for dask dataframes?